# Update on custom relation: is primary key required?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, primary-key

```
UPDATE (
    SELECT
        o.order_id,
        o.shipping_from
    FROM
        orders o,
        items i
    WHERE
        o.item_id = i.item_id
        AND o.shipping_from = 'foot'
        AND i.type = 'ent'
) t
SET
    t.shipping_from = 'car';
```

The inner `SELECT` query returns 2 rows from `orders`. The whole query works well as excepted. `o.order_id` and `i.item_id` are primary keys, `o.item_id` is a foreign key, other columns' name don't match.

When I run an update in this way, is it reuquired to include a primary key in the relation I want to update? Why? If not, how would the DBMS know that a row is located in another table? Sure, `items` doesn't have `shipping_from` field so it's not ambiguous which row I select, but what if it had?

Some data examples:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE type = 'ent';
   ITEM_ID ITEM_SERIAL_CODE     NAME                 BRAND                TYPE         DAILY_COST PURCHASE_DAT
---------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ------------ ---------- ------------
      1007 DC00755250           Dragon costume       Branded              ent               19000 14-DEC.  -15
      1010 SS01003632           Serpentine streamer  Chinese              ent              132500 10-MÁRC. -03

SELECT * FROM orders WHERE shipping_from = 'foot';
  ORDER_ID    ITEM_ID   EVENT_ID LIABLE_PERSON   SHIPPING_T SHIPPING_F ORDER_COMMENT
---------- ---------- ---------- --------------- ---------- ---------- -----------------------------------
      3011       1006       2010 Géza Nagy       car        foot       It will be a great party.
      3018       1009       2011 Ferenc Nagy     boat       foot       Multiple celebs expected.
      3019       1010       2011 Ferenc Balázs   bus        foot       Changing weather, changing seasons.
      3020       1010       2012 Béci Patkó      boat       foot       Bring the stuff to the first floor.
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih Updated the question. Orders with id 3019 and 3020 should be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to what I wanted to know is no. The primary key is not required in the projection list, the `UPDATE`'s effect is the same even if `o.order_id` is not selected in the sub-query. However, this doesn't mean the primary key is unused, thanks to the declarative technique. Whatever including or excluding the primary key, the same execution plan is created to fetch the records which will be updated:

[image: SQL Developer's explain plan view]

Projection doesn't change much here, the DBMS could identify each rows after the hash join operation, see krokodilko's answer.

If you don't select anything from the table (like you type `SELECT 1 FROM ...`), you can't execute the update command, the sub-query's result is just a normal set of some data, it can't be mapped to a table.

I think we should always include the primary key to make it clear to the reader how is the sub-query's result used in the inner-query, which table we plan to update.

Answer (score 2):

> is it reuquired to include a primary key in the relation I want to
>   update? Why?

Yes

---

The answer is in the documentation: [24.1.5 DML Statements and Join Views](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/views.htm#ADMIN-GUID-367FAA9B-269C-41AD-A429-631D144CF36F)

> **Updating a Join View**
>
> An updatable join view (also referred to as a modifiable join view) is a view that contains multiple tables in the
>   top-level FROM clause of the SELECT statement, and is not restricted
>   by the WITH READ ONLY clause.
>
> The rules for updatable join views are shown in the following table.
>   Views that meet these criteria are said to be inherently updatable.
>
> - **General Rule**: Any INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE operation on a join view can modify only one underlying base table at a time.
> - **UPDATE Rule**: All updatable columns of a join view must map to columns of a key-preserved table. See ["Key-Preserved Tables"](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/views.htm#GUID-A661DF5B-A5CE-4569-B5F1-AE8D407E6D30)  for a discussion of key-preserved tables. If the view is defined with the WITH CHECK OPTION clause, then all join columns and all columns of repeated tables are not updatable.
>
> .......................

In the context of the above documentation, a subquery in the UPDATE statement (`UPDATE ( subquery ) SET ...` ) is treated as **the view**, that is like `UPDATE the_view SET ...` - because any view is nothing but a (sub)query.

Comment: Well, maybe it wasn't clear, but what I wanted to ask is do I must include explicity the primary key field in the query or not. I think mappable means something else than required in `SELECT ...`. Running the update without selecting `o.order_id` also worked.